# Selenium IDE cannot find CK Editor

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am new to selenium IDE. Selenium IDE is not able to recognize CK Editor text area. I want to paste some stored data to it.

Comment: May we see your code? We aren't going to be able to get very far without it.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally its good to share the exact nature of your problem in detail, I am still trying to help you on some assumptions! If this is not satisfactory, atleast it can help you share the problem completely.

You may not be able to view inner content of CK Editor directly using Selenium IDE, but you can do it after going into the source code mode. Check this image below:
[image: CKEditor]

Now assuming you want to automate the inputting of some text in the CKEditor text box, get the xpath(or any other locator) for the *Source* button and use *click* command.

Then you can access the text-box of the CKEditor (see the attached image) using a proper locator and automate the text input process.

[image: CKEditor with Source button clicked]

But remember, in the text box you have to enter the text with proper HTML tags `(<p>, <br> etc)`.

Hope this helps!